# Scheduling a satutus change using celery in django

Tags: python, django, celery

In my program, I have scheduled a task that is aimed at changing the status of insurance to **Expiré** if the due date is equal to the current date when I run the program. The script supposes to loop up throughout the Contract's table and fetches the rows that are corresponding to the condition we used in the script. However, it is changing the status of the whole table including rows that should not be affected by the imposed condition.
Here is the jobs.py file that is scheduling the task of changing the status of the insurance to **Expiré** if the condition is true.

```
from assurance_auto.models import Contrat
from datetime import datetime, timedelta,date
from django.conf import settings

def status_schedule(): 
    
    contractList = Contrat.objects.all()
    for contrat in contractList:
        if contrat.get_NbDays()<=date.today() and contrat.statut_assurance=='Encours':
            contractList.update(statut_assurance='Expiré')
            print('Numéro de contrat est :',contrat.numero_de_contrat,\
                ' et le statut est: ',contrat.statut_assurance)
        else:
            break
```

Below is the updater.py file. This function is about scheduling the execution time of the job

```
from datetime import datetime
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from .jobs import status_schedule
def start():
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(status_schedule, 'interval', seconds=5)
    scheduler.start()
```

In the apps.py file, I have the program below which consists of running the updater file once the program is running.

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class AssuranceAutoConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'assurance_auto'
    def ready(self):
        from jobs import updater
        updater.start()
```

[image: Screenshot of the occurring error]
The two circled rows are the ones supposed to change the status to **Expiré**. However, all rows are changing the status to **Expiré** which is not what I want to get as a result.
How can I solve this programming error, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
contractList = Contrat.objects.all()
for contrat in contractList:
    if contrat.NbDays<=date.today() and contrat.statut_assurance=='Encours':
        Contrat.objects.filter(id=contract.id).update(statut_assurance='Expiré')
        print('Numéro de contrat est :',contrat.numero_de_contrat,\
            ' et le statut est: ',contrat.statut_assurance)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not update the `contractList`, since that is a queryset with *all* records, you update that item with:

```
def status_schedule(): 
    for contrat in Contrat.objects.filter(statut_assurance='Encours'):
        if contrat.get_NbDays() <= date.today():
            contrat.statut_assurance = 'Expiré'
            contrat.save()
            print('Numéro de contrat est :',contrat.numero_de_contrat,\
                ' et le statut est: ',contrat.statut_assurance)
```

You should also *not* `break` the loop.

Depending on the implementation of `get_NbDays`, you can also move that to the `.filter(…)` clause and in that case work with a `.update(…)`

Comment: The save() method is raising an error showing that the QuerySet' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: Even if I follow your solution and keep the update() method, I am getting the same issue as before

Comment: @MohamedAbdillah: but it is *not* `contractList`, but `contrat` that you should use (both for `.status_assurance` and `.save()`)...

Comment: I just copied and past what you send to replace with my code but still does not working

Comment: @MohamedAbdillah: exactly *what* is not working? Edit the question with the new version of the code and the full traceback...